# How to commit into the Neo4j repo

Tags: git, neo4j

It's my first time here and my first time using Git .... I'm trying to push new code into the repostiory without success (*I developed something that extends the commands from Cypher adding a properties function*).

Could someone help me ?  *I'm feeling like a dummy! ;)*

Also, I signed and sent the CLA..but I not received any response... I need to wait for this response?

Thanks in advance!!!

Antonio

(the same question was done in : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/AWiEB223saY )

Comment: What git commands have you tried?

Comment: Have you been given access to push directly into the repository?

Comment: Only neo4j core developers can push to the official neo4j repository. You may want to open a pull request with your functionality and unit tests.

Comment: Typically, if you want to commit to a git repo and you haven't been given direct privileges to do so, the protocol for making the change is to fork the repo you want to contribute to, commit push to the fork, and then put in a pull request to the upstream repo.  https://help.github.com/articles/using-pull-requests/

Comment: @ChristopheWillemsen - How I can open a pull request ?

Comment: @FrobberOfBits - Thanks, it was I believe, but I think that is not necessary to create a fork from their repository... I'm trying to clarify this point with the Neo4j developers.

Comment: @mirelon - I try to send commands like `rebase -i`, and others like `push` ... but this question maybe is not for generic repos, I try to find someone from the Neo4j developers that show me what are the exact steps that I need to do in their repository (for example, they told in their guide that is the rebase command that I need to use).

Comment: @Chris -  Doesn't look like that I have direct access to execute a push command.

Comment: @FrobberOfBits - well, finally I decided  to make a fork and pull it. your link was great to introduce to me about it. Thanks a lot.